# Different versions of application use different OpenGL renderer

Tags: gpu, opengl

I have two versions of the same application (same source code, just built with a different version of the wxWidgets library) that use different OpenGL renderers for some reason. I run them using

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia ./wxTest_XX
```

and they print the OpenGL Vendor, Renderer and Version strings. Version 1 (built using the wxWidgets version 3.0.4 installed via `sudo apt install libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev`) prints

```
Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation, Renderer: NVIDIA RTX A5000/PCIe/SSE2, Version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.60.13
```

while version 2 (built using wxWidgets 3.2.1 built from source) prints

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Vendor: Mesa/X.org, Renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits), Version: 3.1 Mesa 21.2.6
```

(notice the warning message printed during startup of the application)

Since I need the application to use the NVidia GPU, I am trying to understand why it is choosing the wrong OpenGL renderer in one case. Other posts on choosing the OpenGL renderer mostly propose `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia`, or relate to situations where it doesn't work at all. But clearly, the system is capable of using the correct GPU, it's just one application that doesn't want to. I am currently trying to understand why it works in one case but not the other, without any luck so far. Trying to search for the `libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate` warning message also didn't yield any helpful results so far.

[I have already as in the forums for the wxWidgets library](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=50089), and they told me it has nothing to do with the library itself, and that I should look at the rest of my system.

**TL;DR:** How can I for my application to use the dedicated NVidia GPU as OpenGL renderer, in a system where other applications manage to do so?

Some details on the system:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- GPU: NVidia RTX A5000 (driver version 525.60.13)
- There is no screen plugged in anywhere, I am connecting via Remote Desktop/xrdp
- Output of `lspci | grep -i vga`:

  ```
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2231 (rev a1)
  43:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)
  ```

Comment: You could find more help here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Can you add `lspci | grep -i vga` on the affected machine?

Comment: @etosan I have added the output to the bottom of the question

Comment: Thus as your output suggests, it seems that another graphics adapter you have is indeed this APSEED card - never saw it myself, but it seems supermicro provided adapter. Second thing you forgot to add is that you are running RDP server there, which further complicates things.

Comment: Either APSEED itself (if it has no acceleration), or, my guess would be, that RDP's xserver is pulling in llvmpipe (software OpenGL emulation). This is complex topic

Comment: If my hunch is right you have to somehow tell to wx display stack to use NVidia GL library instead of generic llvm one. Not sure why this changed between wx versions - but it did.

Comment: Which xserver are you running your application from? Running it from terminal emulator connected to Nvidia hardware bound xserver should work for both wx libraries (ie at the machine's terminal). 

Running it from terminal emulator bound to RDP connected xserver might end up being a challenge. 

What is this application used for - OpenGL drawing or CUDA? If is for OpenGL drawing, you have to be running it on the xserver with OpenGL hardware display present.

For drawing you cannot just start this application from within RDP session.

Comment: @etosan The application should use OpenGL to display some results computed via CUDA. It is being launched simply via RDP (e.g. via a terminal opened in the RDP session), so I assume that means it's running on the "problematic" terminal emulator. What's strange is that the version using the old wxWidgets version manages to properly work (besides some issues with resizing), i.e. I can use CUDA to render onto an OpenGL texture and get that displayed in a window.

Comment: So in my mind, I "simply" need to replicate whatever the old version of wxWidgets is doing with the new version. Unfortunately, I have no idea how I would achieve that, or which part of the system is choosing the wrong OpenGL renderer, or if that's even the root of the problem instead of just another symptom

Comment: The issue of OpenGL is quite complicated. I don know what RDP implementation you used

Comment: It is confounded by usage of display technologies. We have two major GUI "servers" on Linux XOrg (historical quite robust), "wayland" based derivatives (new performant underdeveloped/problematic). I am now pretty sure that in the RDP scenario you are running Xorg. When logged physically on console we don't knowwhat you are running it could be "wayland" or traditional Xorg. I don't know what RDP implementation you are using, by assume xrdp from neutrinolabs. That one works by loading special x11 "driver" into XOrg xorgxrdp - which "replaces" X11s graphics card by itself.

Comment: "xorgxrdp" has no OpenGL capabilities besides llvmpipe, I guess. If I understand nvidia properly, CUDA should work at all circumstances, problem is OpenGL window - maybe it would be for the best to extract CUDA rendered image into device independent form (some kind of wxbitmap) and use that for display?

Comment: You also can try launching your application from RDP session, when you also have other Xorg, bound to physical display, running. Ie logon to desktop physically to start xserver there, note it's $DISPLAY, and try to launch your application from within RDP at the same time by prefixing DISPLAY variable of the physically bound X11 before your app. I.e.`env DISPLAY=$PHYSDIPLAY ./wxTest_XX`, you should see application window spawn on physical OpenGL, working, while terminal lines (stdfds) will remain attached to the terminal emulator in RDP. If that is the case, you issue is GPU access arbitration.